# Angular 2 -POST 401 Unauthorized

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, api

I am using angular 2. I want to post data using API, but I get unauthorized access error...

Can someone help me figure out why am I getting this error?

[image: 401 Unauthorized]

Comment: You need to share more details with related code

Comment: Yes need API code and code that you are calling API call from service

Answer (score 6):

Check with the headers you configured for **Authorization** in service.ts file. If it's not you need to add the headers to the URL.

Headers can be used as

```
const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
    })
}
```

And add this to the URL as follows.
As and example:

```
getUsers() {
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'users', httpOptions);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check your API authentication scheme. you might need to login first ( if using cookies ). Or provide some authentication header.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is missing or wrong content type header.

For post method requests your content type should be one of the standard form types: application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data